# Why is org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl not being garbage collected?

Tags: spring, garbage-collection, heap-memory, tomcat6, opencms

I have a website deployed to a tomcat server which has been very rapidly using up its available heap space (Old Gen) then crashing. When I took a heap dump i found that most (if not all) of the space is being taken up by lots of org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl instances (802 to be precise with a keep alive size of 541mb) (referenced from org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader -> java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$HashEntry)

About the server
The server is tomcat 6 proxied by apache2 using proxypass.

About the software
I am using opencms to content manage the webapp and as such all the code is called through its template classes
Hibernate is accessed using springs HibernateTemplate. The data source is held in tomcat and is accessed through org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean and injected into my datasource (org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource), the session factory is configured as below.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list><value>com.someobjects.SomeObject</value>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Does any one know why org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl is not being garbage collected?

I can provide any further information required... I really am at a loss with this one. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would expect that you only have a single session factory instance in your application context. How do you load your spring application context?